# Good places to deploy a simple Django website

Tags: python, django, hosting

I am looking for options on places to host a Django site.

Should I find a service that already has the proper programs and dependencies installed?

Or can I gain access to a server and install them myself?

Answer (score 1):

- Webfaction
- Heroku
- Google App Engine
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Windows Azure

But, cheaper, do it yourself. VPS's these days are quite cheap (digitalocean.com $5/month). An easy to manage combination: Ubuntu + Nginx + Gunicorn, and follow some tutorials about how to secure and update your VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Hosting yourself can be cheaper, but you will have to spend some time maintaing the system to keep it safe. Choosing a service may be a bit more expansive but you don't have to deal with the system itself.
Choose your best.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need somewhere to play around with I would recommend something like [heroku](https://www.heroku.com).

It's easy to deploy apps, free for small apps and you don't have to worry about sysadmin side of things if you do not need to.